# How to customize table columns sizes in ActiveAdmin index pages?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm trying to customize the index pages in my admin section I've created with ActiveAdmin.
I want to set the size for each column in CSS2.

ActiveAdmin create a layout like:

```
<table [...] class="index_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sortable"><a href="#">Field 1</a></th>
      <th class="sortable"><a href="#">Field 2</a></th>
      <th class="sortable"><a href="#">Field 3</a></th>
      <th class="sortable"><a href="#">Field 4</a></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>value 3</td>
      <td>value 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add a class or an id for each `<th>` section, as:

```
<table [...] class="index_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="first sortable"><a href="#">Field 1</a></th>
      <th class="second sortable"><a href="#">Field 2</a></th>
      <th class="third sortable"><a href="#">Field 3</a></th>
      <th class="fourth sortable"><a href="#">Field 4</a></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>value 3</td>
      <td>value 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Maybe, it's not the best way to do it?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: I think it's ok to use this classes, unless you have a lot of `<th>` tags :)

Comment: yeah, sure, just use classes. i sometimes use 'readable' classes as .w200{width:200px} - which could be handier than first, second, third...

Comment: Thx for your replies. But How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's a way to do it:

In active_admin.css.scss you can add some styles to customise the index of the Headline model for example:

```
body.admin_headlines table.index_table thead tr th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px !important;
}

body.admin_headlines table.index_table thead tr th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

And so on...